# iDRAC 7 Enterprise does not work properly

Tags: dell, remote-access, drac

I have problems with login to iDRAC via web browser to new DELL R320 server. 
I see this problem first time.

On browser login screen looks uncomplete(Chrome, Firefox, IE) :
[image: log screen]

I know where is login and password so after typing all and click login all I see is this :
[image]

Firebug report that there is an error 404 for

```
 GET locale_pl.json 404 Not Found 10.X.X.X 176 B 10.X.X.X:443
```

Configuration is default with static ip.

Have you seen any thing similar to this and maybe you know how to repair it.

Is this problem with my iDRAC card?

EDIT1:
I did `racadm racreset soft` after login to iDRAC via ssh  didn't help ... still web ui of iDRAC is corrupted.

Comment: Is all of your firmware up to date? Can you log into the iDRAC via SSH? Have you restarted the iDRAC from the OS?

Comment: @mfinni I dont know if all firmware is up to date a got this server today morning it's brand new server. Yes I can log in via ssh. And how can I restart iDRAC from OS ???

Comment: You can reset the DRAC from the OS using the configuration utilities provided by Dell for your operating system. It's the same utility that can reconfigure the DRAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your browser set to send Polish as the preferred language? It appears that the DRAC will try and load a locale file for anything but English and only some of them exist (French, German, Spanish) :/

Comment: Oooh - nice catch, this sounds likely.

Comment: http://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_software/esuprt_remote_ent_sys_mgmt/integrated-dell-remote-access-cntrllr-7-v1.00.00_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf   : `Viewing Localized Versions of Web Interface
iDRAC7 Web interface is supported in the following languages:
• English (en-us)
• French (fr)
• German (de)
• Spanish (es)
• Japanese (ja)
• Simplified Chinese (zh-cn)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you can get in via SSH but not the browser, the DRAC is semi-functional, not dead.

The first thing you should do when deploying a new server is update the firmware(s). If you're a big organization, you'll have a standard accepted level so you should update to that level. If not (sounds like your situation), simply use the latest from the vendor. BIOS and DRAC firmware both; and check to see if your model has any other management bits that might need updates. For the R320, you've got the lifecycle controller as well.

After all that - You've issued a soft reset and that didn't improve things. Try a hard reset.

After all that - Try wiping the DRAC config entirely and starting over.

If none of those options work, call Dell support. This is a brand new server; perhaps it is broken. I assume you've tried to get into the DRAC from more than one workstation?

Further edit - looks like smin, below, has the correct answer. You may be using a browser that is requesting an unsupported language, per the DRAC documentation. So, above when I said the first thing to do was upgrade the firmware? Even before that, you should read the manuals.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the exact same problem.
First of all, IDRAC 7 runs only on Firefox 3.5+ or Internet Explorer 6-10 (IE11 and Chrome are not supported).
In my case the solution was to clean cookies in the browser (while the browser is closed) and in the next time you open it, you will see the right text in the third box, you should see "This IDRAC" as the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Update iDRAc7 version to 1.51.51 which has below fix.

When the operating system language or Browser language has unsupported GUI language, the
Login page always appears blank. To resolve this issue, a fix is added to load the page with
English, if the user selects an unsupported browser language or Operating System language.

This may resolve your issue.