# Can't get OMSA installed on Dell R610 w/ Centos 6

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, dell-openmanage

Trying to use the iDRAC racadm command to reset the login password for the iDRAC web gui.

So I installed OMSA (found this link http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/f/4469/t/19490204)

```
wget -q -O - http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/bootstrap.cgi | bash
yum install srvadmin-all
```

No issues with above.

PROBLEM:

```
root@server [~]# racadm config -g cfgUserAdmin -o cfgUserAdminPassword -i 2 "newpassword"
-bash: racadm: command not found

root@server [~]# rpm -q -a --requires srvadmin-all                                        
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
srvadmin-base = 8.1.0
srvadmin-idrac = 8.1.0
srvadmin-oslog = 8.1.0
srvadmin-rac4 = 8.1.0
srvadmin-rac5 = 8.1.0
srvadmin-server-cli = 8.1.0
srvadmin-server-snmp = 8.1.0
srvadmin-standardAgent = 8.1.0
srvadmin-storageservices = 8.1.0
srvadmin-webserver = 8.1.0
```

EDIT: had to run "sh" like this, within the directory path. New error.

```
root@server [/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin]# sh racadm config -g cfgUserAdmin -o cfgUserAdminPassword -i 2 "newpassword"
ERROR: Failed to set the object value. 
Possible reason may be that Local Configuration using RACADM is disabled.
===============================================================================
IMPORTANT NOTE!
The RAC is unable to communicate with the BMC. This condition may
occur because of (1) no BMC is present, (2) missing or disfunctional
IPMI-related software components. Many RAC features depend on BMC
connectivity in order to work properly, and you may see failures
as a result.
```

UPDATE 8/25:

root@server [~]# racadm config -g cfgUserAdmin -o cfgUserAdminPassword -i 2 newpassword
Object value modified successfully

UPDATE #2

```
root@server [~]# racadm getconfig -g cfgUserAdmin -i 2
# cfgUserAdminIndex=2
cfgUserAdminUserName=root
# cfgUserAdminPassword=******** (Write-Only)
cfgUserAdminEnable=1
cfgUserAdminPrivilege=0x000001ff
cfgUserAdminIpmiLanPrivilege=4
cfgUserAdminIpmiSerialPrivilege=4
cfgUserAdminSolEnable=1
```

Comment: Have you checked that OMSA services are running (including IPMI) with `/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh restart`

Comment: @sfk thanks but although results in command look good, still getting invalid login credential on my idrac6 interface. Updated my original post.

Comment: Also check that root account is *enabled* with this command `racadm getconfig -g cfgUserAdmin -i 2`

Comment: @sfk Yes it is enabled. See updated post with output.

Comment: Could you check that `racadm -r ip -u root -p newpassword getsysinfo` runs correctly ?

Comment: @sfk I ran that and got "ERROR: Unable to connect to RAC at specified IP address."

Comment: Do you have a shared RJ45 cable (for both Operating System & Idrac) ie not using the dedicated Eth port ? If yes, could you run the same racadm command from another server or workstation (possibly windows) ?

Comment: @sfk, I use a dedicated RJ45 cable for idrac, and a dedicated cable/port for the regular eth0 public access.

Comment: Have you change 'ip' with your actual idrac IP address in the previous command ?

Comment: @sfk Yes I did. The interface itself comes up fine, just keeps giving me login credentials invalid message.

Comment: The browser is launch from the server itself or from a remote workstation ? Could you check Ip connectivity from OS to iDrac ?

Comment: @sfk I'm not sure what you mean. I am logged into ssh as root in the server itself, the Linux box. I can ping the iDRAC IP address too. Via browser on my local Windows computer, I can pull up the iDRAC page too, same IP. I simply cannot login though.

Comment: Can you `ssh root@idrac_ip_adress` with the new password from either your windows computer or from you linux box ?

Comment: @sfk ssh: connect to host **ipaddress** port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Again, check your ip connectivity from the linux box to idrac (you should be able to ping your idrac). Also, check the idrac logs `racadm getraclog`

Comment: @sfk Ok, I had to whitelist the drac IP in the linux server's firewall. I was able to login to the drac via ssh with the password I reset to. Here's the weird thing now. When I try to login to root / newpass via the drac gui, I don't get a login credential error message, it simply refreshes the login page. When I login via ssh into the drac, the same password does work fine and I'm put into this prompt: /admin1->

Comment: @sfk, I figured something out. I was trying to login via Firefox, only refreshes login page. I tried IE11, able to login but every link says "undefined". I tried Edge browser, I can login but although links show text, they don't even click. Weird issue. I even already whitelisted https://dracipaddress in the java configuration too.

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com/questions/605473/idrac-login-loop for the solution for silent idrac login failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always had to do the following steps.  Bear with me because I don't have a dell machine in front of me anymore.

```
    cd /opt/dell/srvadmin/etc
    # there is some auto*.sh file, I can't remember the name, run this it will 
    ./auto*.sh
    srvadmin-services.sh restart
    # This may not be in your path, if not, there is a profile script in /etc/profile.d to source
```

The srvadmin-services.sh also make sure all the dell agents and modules are running, along with ipmi.

Make sure that racadm points to the correct one for you drac version, in this case, racadmin-idrac6 I believe.  It is usually a symbolic link.

Comment: Thanks @lsd I get it running, but I can't get the password reset. See my updated OP.